# Zend Plugin works only in one module

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

I have created a plugin, that ckecks authorization status and gives access for using application. This plugin works fine, but in whole project. I want to make it works only in admin module. How can I do this?
I have defined plugin in application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.authcheck = Application_Plugin_AuthCheck
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
admin.resources.frontController.plugins.authcheck = Application_Plugin_AuthCheck
```

Second way:
check in plugin module's name:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'admin') {
    //process
}
```